# Combine leaflet click ability with shiny widget to subset and display data in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

In the `shiny` app below I want when the app starts to display a map with the selected from the widget counties and also a table below.

Then if I click on a county on the map the table to be affected and show only the data from the clicked county also the shiny widget should show only the selected county.

Then if I select more counties from the `shiny` widget the map and the table and the map should be affected accordingly.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)  # Make sure you have this package installed
library(raster)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Sample dataframe (replace this with your actual data)
df <- data.frame(
  Indicator = c("primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary"),
  Geography = c("Ventura", "Orange", "Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte"),
  State = c(rep("California",6)),
  Year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008),
  Category = c("Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population"),
  Subcategory = c("Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population"),
  Numerator = c(NA, 2618, 124, 0, 0, 13),
  Denominator = c(NA, 532102, 20483, 11, 295, 2466),
  Rate = c(60.3, 49.2, 60.5, 0.0, 0.0, 52.7)
)


# Load USA polygon data
USA <- getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("County Rate Map"),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "gr",
    label = "County",
    choices = unique(df$Geography),
    selected = unique(df$Geography),
    multiple = T
  ),
  
  leafletOutput("map"),
  dataTableOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Merge the USA polygon data with the dataframe
  merged_data <- sp::merge(USA, df, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = c("NAME_1","NAME_2"), by.y = c("State","Geography"))
  dfpls<-reactive({
    df<-subset(merged_data,NAME_2%in%input$gr)
    df
  })
  
  #calls map
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    # Load your data for the choropleth
    #data <- read.csv("your_data.csv")  # Replace with the path to your data file
    
    # Merge the data with the US states geojson data
    #merged_data <- merge(us_states, data, by.x = "state", by.y = "State", all.x = TRUE)
    # temp <- sp::merge(USA, df, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = c("NAME_2"), by.y = c("Geography"))
    temp <- dfpls()
    
    # Determine the maximum value excluding NA values
    max_value <- max(temp$Rate, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Calculate the maximum value rounded up to the nearest multiple of 20
    max_rounded <- ceiling(max_value / 9) 
    
    # Create the bins vector
    bins <- c(seq(0, max_value, by = max_rounded), max_value)
    pal <- colorBin("Blues", domain = as.numeric(temp$Rate), bins = bins)
    
    
    leaflet(temp) %>%
      setView(lng = -118.2437, lat = 34.0522, zoom = 7)%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(Rate),
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        layerId = temp$NAME_2,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 5,
          color = "#666",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          bringToFront = TRUE),
        label =  lapply(
          paste0(
            "County: ", temp$NAME_2, "<br>",
            "Rate: ",temp$Rate, "<br>",
            "Denominator: ", temp$Denominator,"<br>",
            "Numerator:",temp$Numerator
          ),
          HTML
        ),
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight" = "normal"
                       , padding = "3px 8px"
                       , textsize = "15px"
                       , direction = "auto" ))
      ) %>%
      addLegend(title = "Measure Rate Map",pal = pal, values = ~Rate, opacity = 0.7,
                position = "bottomright")
  })
  
  # Create a reactive subset of data based on selected county
  selected_county_data <- reactive({
    # click_county <- input$map_click
    click_county <- input$map_shape_click
    
    # print(click_county)
    if (is.null(click_county)) {
      dfpls()
    } else {
      clicked_county <- click_county$id
      subset(dfpls(), NAME_2 == clicked_county)
    }
  })
  output$dt<-renderDataTable({
    selected_county_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `merged_data` object other states with the same name counties are still kept.  So, define a data frame while creating `selected_county_data()` object and keep only the state(s) available in the `df` object.  Also, in `output$map` keep in `temp` only the states in `df`. Then, use `updatePickerInput` to display the counties clicked on the map.

Lastly, if Rate is 0, it is hard to see where the selected county is since you are using `fillColor = ~pal(Rate)`.  So, I have defined it as 33 (arbitrary number).  You can define it as you wish.

Try this.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)  # Make sure you have this package installed
library(raster)
library(shinyWidgets)
# Sample dataframe (replace this with your actual data)
df <- data.frame(
  Indicator = c("primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary"),
  Geography = c("Ventura", "Orange", "Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte"),
  State = c(rep("California",6)),
  Year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008),
  Category = c("Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population", "Total Population"),
  Subcategory = c("Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population", "Total population"),
  Numerator = c(NA, 2618, 124, 0, 0, 13),
  Denominator = c(NA, 532102, 20483, 11, 295, 2466),
  Rate = c(60.3, 49.2, 60.5, 33, 33, 52.7)  ### If zero, it is not highlighted in map as you are using fillColor = ~pal(Rate); randomly assigned 33
)


# Load USA polygon data
USA <- getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("County Rate Map"),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "gr",
    label = "County",
    choices = unique(df$Geography),
    selected = unique(df$Geography),
    multiple = T
  ),
  
  leafletOutput("map"),
  dataTableOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Merge the USA polygon data with the dataframe
  merged_data <- sp::merge(USA, df, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = c("NAME_1","NAME_2"), by.y = c("State","Geography"))

  dfpls<- eventReactive(input$gr, {
    df<- subset(merged_data,NAME_2%in%input$gr)
    df
  })
  
  #calls map
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
 
    states <- unique(df$State)
    temp <- subset(dfpls(), NAME_1 %in% states)
    
    # Determine the maximum value excluding NA values
    max_value <- max(temp$Rate, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    # Calculate the maximum value rounded up to the nearest multiple of 20
    max_rounded <- ceiling(max_value / 9) 
    
    # Create the bins vector
    bins <- c(seq(0, max_value, by = max_rounded), max_value)
    pal <- colorBin("Blues", domain = as.numeric(temp$Rate), bins = bins)
    
    leaflet(temp) %>%
      setView(lng = -118.2437, lat = 36.0522, zoom = 5)%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(Rate),
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        layerId = temp$NAME_2,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 5,
          color = "#666",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          bringToFront = TRUE),
        label =  lapply(
          paste0(
            "County: ", temp$NAME_2, "<br>",
            "Rate: ",temp$Rate, "<br>",
            "Denominator: ", temp$Denominator,"<br>",
            "Numerator:",temp$Numerator
          ),
          HTML
        ),
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight" = "normal"
                       , padding = "3px 8px"
                       , textsize = "15px"
                       , direction = "auto" ))
      ) %>%
      addLegend(title = "Measure Rate Map",pal = pal, values = ~Rate, opacity = 0.7,
                position = "bottomright")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_shape_click,{
    click_county <- input$map_shape_click
    choices <- unique(df$Geography)
    selected <- click_county$id
    updatePickerInput(session = session,"gr",choices=choices, selected=selected)
  },ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  # Create a reactive subset of data based on selected county
  selected_county_data <- reactive({
    req(dfpls())
    
    click_county <- input$map_shape_click
    states <- unique(df$State)
    dfa <- as.data.frame(dfpls())
    
    if (is.null(click_county)) {
      df <- dfa[dfa$NAME_1 %in% states,]
    } else {
      clicked_county <- click_county$id
      df <- subset(dfa, NAME_1 %in% states &  NAME_2 %in% input$gr)
    }
    df
  })
  
  output$dt<-renderDataTable({
    req(selected_county_data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The code produces the desired output, but it might be worth a brief explanation of what you did - there are a few interventions here and highlighting them would make it easier for people viewing the answer to know what had to change.

Comment: I have made it a bit more complex but based on your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77011781/subset-a-dataframe-based-on-leaflet-click-event-and-shiny-widgets