# Merge dataframe with spatial polygons dataframe to create a leaflet map

Tags: r, merge, leaflet, polygon

I have the df below:

```
    df<-structure(list(Geography = c("Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte", 
"Calaveras", "Colusa", "Contra Costa", "Del Norte", "El Dorado", 
"Fresno", "Glenn", "Humboldt", "Imperial", "Inyo", "Kern", "Kings", 
"Lake", "Lassen", "Los Angeles", "Madera", "Marin", "Mariposa", 
"Mendocino", "Merced", "Modoc", "Mono", "Monterey", "Napa", "Nevada", 
"Orange", "Placer", "Plumas", "Riverside", "Sacramento", "San Benito", 
"San Bernardino", "San Diego", "San Francisco", "San Joaquin", 
"San Luis Obispo", "San Mateo", "Santa Barbara", "Santa Clara", 
"Santa Cruz", "Shasta", "Sierra", "Siskiyou", "Solano", "Sonoma", 
"Stanislaus", "Sutter", "Tehama", "Trinity", "Tulare", "Tuolumne", 
"Ventura", "Yolo", "Yuba"), State = c("California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California"), Mean_Rate = c(69.37, 0, 6.16868421052632, 54.27, 
7.63589743589744, 20.5621951219512, 57.2971428571429, 0, 60.109603960396, 
47.1339261744966, 0, 75.0892156862745, 50.8058064516129, 4.75, 
53.5912828947368, 80.9712096774194, 41.2157692307692, 35.8066666666667, 
54.6651008645533, 44.2918390804598, 60.7228571428571, 0, 44.5651785714286, 
54.9762222222222, 0, 0, 48.5370642201835, 84.9582203389831, 28.840652173913, 
43.2647058823529, 69.707573964497, 0, 51.4626888217523, 72.0408490566038, 
50.8892727272727, 59.41583081571, 46.6480415430267, 60.9259040590406, 
58.2489830508475, 46.0581739130435, 55.436442687747, 63.0378894472362, 
58.0167076923077, 68.7685211267606, 62.2454901960784, 0, 0, 63.9771369294606, 
76.2142857142857, 46.1640585774059, 61.719746835443, 13.66975, 
0, 52.0951428571429, 0, 63.8743706293706, 74.8387671232877, 49.1536666666667
), Mean_Numerator = c(125.692771084337, 0, 0.552631578947368, 
18.5688073394495, 0.538461538461538, 2.07317073170732, 71.012987012987, 
0, 15.5049504950495, 70.8489932885906, 0, 16.7843137254902, 20.7903225806452, 
0.263157894736842, 69.3486842105263, 24.2983870967742, 5.88461538461539, 
2.68888888888889, 586.896253602305, 15.6666666666667, 20.5357142857143, 
0, 8.14285714285714, 28.8166666666667, 0, 0, 39.4678899082569, 
18.1779661016949, 4, 149.532507739938, 32.4733727810651, 0, 135.957703927492, 
133.962264150943, 7.96363636363636, 153.060422960725, 156.127596439169, 
56.4169741697417, 60.8915254237288, 16.4782608695652, 53.0276679841897, 
42.2713567839196, 131.612307692308, 27.1408450704225, 19.9117647058824, 
0, 0, 33.9294605809129, 44.1122448979592, 42.9916317991632, 12.4810126582278, 
2.425, 0, 49.4897959183673, 0, 70.8601398601399, 22.513698630137, 
9.66666666666667), Mean_Denominator = c(24542.6195652174, 6.3125, 
376.237704918033, 2911.54469273743, 430.812849162011, 383.712290502793, 
15067.5865921788, 358.354748603352, 1918.27653631285, 19313.8826815642, 
492.63407821229, 1751.32681564246, 3562.44972067039, 253.156424581006, 
17219.9245810056, 2698.52793296089, 877.45251396648, 323.379888268156, 
153493.768156425, 2870.3938547486, 2809.06145251397, 159.022346368715, 
1229.22067039106, 5029.57541899441, 42.2458100558659, 156.248603351955, 
7763.35754189944, 1762.0530726257, 879.885474860335, 46183.5754189944, 
4562.38826815642, 167.128491620112, 36757.3994413408, 24145.1117318436, 
920.5, 36313.5474860335, 47201.1201117318, 10836.5, 12716.4916201117, 
3146.09217877095, 10270.2150837989, 7017.5251396648, 29184.4441340782, 
3758.47765363128, 2509.11731843575, 20.0949720670391, 438.54748603352, 
5917.80167597765, 6000.43016759776, 9523.34636871508, 1621.44413407821, 
889.036312849162, 125.994413407821, 9454.64804469274, 541.192737430168, 
12499.8826815642, 2888.31284916201, 1478.15083798883)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -58L), groups = structure(list(
    Geography = c("Alameda", "Alpine", "Amador", "Butte", "Calaveras", 
    "Colusa", "Contra Costa", "Del Norte", "El Dorado", "Fresno", 
    "Glenn", "Humboldt", "Imperial", "Inyo", "Kern", "Kings", 
    "Lake", "Lassen", "Los Angeles", "Madera", "Marin", "Mariposa", 
    "Mendocino", "Merced", "Modoc", "Mono", "Monterey", "Napa", 
    "Nevada", "Orange", "Placer", "Plumas", "Riverside", "Sacramento", 
    "San Benito", "San Bernardino", "San Diego", "San Francisco", 
    "San Joaquin", "San Luis Obispo", "San Mateo", "Santa Barbara", 
    "Santa Clara", "Santa Cruz", "Shasta", "Sierra", "Siskiyou", 
    "Solano", "Sonoma", "Stanislaus", "Sutter", "Tehama", "Trinity", 
    "Tulare", "Tuolumne", "Ventura", "Yolo", "Yuba"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
        36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
        47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
        58L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -58L), .drop = TRUE))
```

and Im trying to merge it with

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
USA <- getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 2)
    temp <- sp::merge(USA, df, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = c("NAME_1","NAME_2"), by.y = c("State","Geography"))
```

but the means in my new data are full of `NAs` my final goal is to create a leaflet map with the mean `Rate`,`Numerator` and `Denominator` for each county like:

```
oh_sp <- temp[temp$NAME_1 == "California", ]


# Determine the maximum value excluding NA values
max_value <- max(oh_sp$Rate, na.rm = TRUE)

# Calculate the maximum value rounded up to the nearest multiple of 20
max_rounded <- ceiling(max_value / 9) 

# Create the bins vector
bins <- c(seq(0, max_value, by = max_rounded), max_value)
pal <- colorBin("Blues", domain = as.numeric(oh_sp$Rate), bins = bins)

library(leaflet)
leaflet(oh_sp) %>%
  setView(lng = -118.2437, lat = 34.0522, zoom = 7)%>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(Rate),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666",
      dashArray = "",
      fillOpacity = 0.7,
      bringToFront = TRUE),
      label =  lapply(
        paste0(
          "County: ", oh_sp$NAME_2, "<br>",
          "Rate: ",oh_sp$Rate, "<br>",
          "Denominator: ", oh_sp$Denominator,"<br>",
          "Numerator:",oh_sp$Numerator
        ),
        HTML
      ),
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal"
                   , padding = "3px 8px"
                   , textsize = "15px"
                   , direction = "auto" ))
     ) %>%
  addLegend(title = "Measure Rate Map",pal = pal, values = ~Rate, opacity = 0.7,
            position = "bottomright")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp::merge()` default for `all.x` is  `TRUE`, meaning that the result will include all records from `x` (your `USA`, 3148 features) and if there are no matches in `y`(your `df`, 58 rows) it sets all those values to `NA`, basically a left join. Try with `all.x = FALSE`:

```r
USA <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "usa", level = 2)
temp <- sp::merge(USA, df, all.x = FALSE, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = c("NAME_1","NAME_2"), by.y = c("State","Geography"))
# 58 features instead of 3148:
temp[, c("Mean_Rate", "Mean_Numerator", "Mean_Denominator")]
#> class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#> features    : 58 
#> extent      : -124.4156, -114.1295, 32.53088, 42.00983  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> variables   : 3
#> names       :        Mean_Rate,   Mean_Numerator, Mean_Denominator 
#> min values  :                0,                0,           6.3125 
#> max values  : 84.9582203389831, 586.896253602305, 153493.768156425
mapview::mapview(temp, zcol = "Mean_Rate")
```

[image: mapview]
<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If your packages are more or less up to date, that code of yours should generate few fat warnings about packages retiring in a month (Oct 2023!) and removal of `getData`, so perhaps consider switching sooner rather than later.